# How can I pass dynamic values in the URL?

Tags: python, url, locust

I am capturing `key=value` pairs from a response body and want to send the same value in the get end point URL as below.

I tried this, which does not work:

```
self.client.get("auth/logout?type=user&refresh_token=" + str(self.refresh_token),
                     headers={"access_token": str(self.access_token)},
                     catch_response=True)
```

Comment: What happens when you try it? Do you get an error? Does it try to get a different URL?

Answer (score 0):

How about using Python's f-string?

```
self.client.get(f"auth/logout?type=user&refresh_token={self.refresh_token}",
                headers={"access_token": f"{self.access_token}"},
                catch_response=True) `
```

But that your code doesn't work has very likely to do with some logics of the get() method.

Comment: I tried with f-string its adding some characters in the beginning and end 
refresh_token=%5B'Qc_Uute9labjVnDZ0Tiq5Q3Kz6I9QJUO3_NtJO_cExU'%5D